# Why does the compiler tell me I need to unwrap a Bool (non-optional?)

Tags: swift, option-type

According the the Swift header for `String`

the property `isEmpty` is a `Bool` (not an optional right?)

```
public var isEmpty: Bool { get }
```

but in my code, when I try to write:

```
!sender.titleOfSelectedItem?.isEmpty
```

> Value of optional type `Bool?` not unwrapped, did you mean to use "?"
>   or "!"

Why does the compiler think that `isEmpty` is an optional?

Is it because the object that contains the property is currently an optional?

`titleOfSelectedItem` is a `String?`

or am I just missing something entirely, here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sender.titleOfSelectedItem?.isEmpty` is an *optional chain* and has the type `Bool?` because it can return `nil` if `titleOfSelectedItem` is `nil`.

You should decide how you want to handle the `nil` case.  You can combine the *optional chain* with the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely unwrap the result:

```
// treat nil as empty
let empty = sender.titleOfSelectedItem?.isEmpty ?? true
```

or you can compare the value to `false`:

```
if sender.titleOfSelectedItem?.isEmpty == false {
    // value isn't nil and it isn't empty
}
```

or you can compare to value to `true`:

```
if sender.titleOfSelectedItem?.isEmpty == true {
    // value isn't nil and it is an empty String
}
```

Comment: So any property of an optional becomes an optional when chained?  I guess I just assumed that optional binding would break out when the it found the receiver (optional) to be nil, and wouldn't bother checking the properties down the chain

Comment: The property doesn't become an optional.  The result of the optional chain is an optional.  If any link in the chain is `nil`, the chain does break and return `nil`. Because the chain can have `nil` as a possible result, the type of the result has to be optional because only an optional can be `nil`.  This is *optional chaining*.  Optional binding is `if let variable = optional expression`.  You can combine the two because the *optional expression* can be an *optional chain*.

Comment: ah okay, totally get it now, was confusing the optional chain and optional binding.  thanks for the explanation!